# Angular2 is based on the Angular-CLI, correct?

Tags: mongodb, angular2

Angular2 is based on the Angular-CLI, correct?

So When I run `ng serve` there is a machine spun up at `localhost:4200`. Now if I want to add a database, a lot of people end up packaging Node.JS along and we have:

- Node server @ 3000 [or whatever your choice]
- Angular Server @ 4200
- MongoDB @ port 12701

To me this seems redundant, because I only need one server and one database.  So I am curious, is this split because people want to maintain angular and node.js separately?  Node.JS can talk with the database and just redirect all page requests to index.html (which angular has covered).

So what's the server at localhost:4200 for?

Comment: ng serve is only for development

Answer (score 3):

> Angular2 is based on the Angular-CLI, correct?

No, that's not correct. The CLI is simply one way to get a project up and running, but there are others.

> is this split because people want to maintain angular and node.js separately?

Yes, you can then serve the Angular front end and Node backend completely separately. They communicate only over HTTP, making it easy to do things like switch front end technologies without switching the back end and vice versa, or load balancing the back end across multiple instances, or moving the front end to static files on a CDN, or ...

> what's the server at localhost:4200 for?

For serving the front end to the client. Once the client is running the front end, it makes requests to the back end. You *could* serve the front end files from Node too, but then you don't get the advantages outlined above. This may or may not be worth it for you.